# Java serialization usage

Tags: java, serialization, syntax

### I have a question about java Serialization.

---

### Simple example:

Class **footballer** with paramaters *age*, *height*, *name*, **favorite football** (class) with parameter *size* and *brand*.

If I serialize **footballer** class, do i also serialize the values of the **football**, or just that it has a **footbal** class, and that i have to serialize the **footbal** seperatly?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you serialize **footballer** , you serialize every field (including **football** and this has to be `Serializable` too, otherwise `Non-Serializable Object exception` will come) in that class unless you declare a field as `transient`.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the answer I was looking for. I'm studying IT, and the subject wasn't exactly clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the "favorite football" class also has to implement the Serializable interface and meet the same requirements of being serializable.